# angular bootstrap UibModal with component error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-components

I am trying to use angular bootstrap UibModal with AngularJS 1.5 component using typescript.

I have defined the component and the component's controller is a class. Now when I do $uibModal.open(...), it finds the component but couldn't load the controller. It fails with this error

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- TempController"
```

My code is as below:-

Component:-

```
 export function TempComponent(): ng.IComponentOptions {
  return {
    bindings: {
      resolve: '<',
      close: '&',
      dismiss: '&'
    },
    controller: TempController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: require('./Temp.html')
  };
}


angular
  .module('moduleName')
  .component('tempComponent', TempComponent());
```

Controller:-

```
export class TempController {

  public static $inject: string[] = [''];

  public someData: string;

  public resolve?: { [key: string]: string | Function | Array<string | Function> | Object };

  public close: Function;
  public dismiss: Function;


  public $onInit(): void {
    this.someData= <string>this.resolve.someData;
  }

  public ok(): void {
    this.close();
  }

  public cancel(): void {
    this.dismiss('cancel');
  }
}

angular.module('moduleName')
  .controller('tempController', TempController);
```

Using UIBModal:-

```
$uibModal.open({component: tempComponent, resolve: .......})
```

Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What's your `index.html` look like?

Comment: temp.html:-

<div>{{vm.someData}}</div>

Comment: And I am opening the dialog on a button click.

Comment: That's not your `index.html`..what is your main page/entry point?